# Revert getElementsByClassName to original browser version

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an existing web page that has all sorts of javascript that I'm not able to edit. I only have access to a certain part of the page to do my stuff. Now the problem is using jQuery. The previous developer had modified the `getElementsByClassName` method with a custom version, which I'm assuming is kind of polyfill for IE. But this breaks jQuery that uses `getElementsByClassName` on supported browsers.

Now how may I revert `getElementsByClassName` to its original version before my code is executed. I can't find the original method anywhere online. Not using jQuery is not really an option as I'm trying to integrate a big piece of code written with jQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just delete the the modification the made to the function? Would that break some other stuff?

Comment: How was the override done? Perhaps they left a reference to the old function?

Comment: A reference to the original would need to have been kept in another variable. Otherwise, the reassignment renders the native definition out of reach to JavaScript. If needed, you could again redefine it with a specification-compliant polyfill.

Comment: @Kemal, I have no access to edit the existing javascript. @Jack, it was done this way, `document.getElementsByClassName = function(cls,n,t) { // custom stuff}`, original function completely overridden. @Rob, jQuery internally uses native class selector in browsers with such support. @Jonathan, no reference to original method kept, so I'm wondering if anyone knows.

Comment: Why not simple `document.getElementsByClassName=function (theclass) { return document.querySelectorAll('.' + theclass'); }`?

Comment: @Pratheep I assume Kemal meant `delete document.getElementsByClassName`, which will remove the new version and restore the old version (on `document.__proto__.getElementsByClassName`).

Comment: Thanks guys. `delete document.getElementsByClassName` seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the prototype chain of `document` wasn't altered, you could restore it by deleting the current implementation, as mentioned in the comments:

```
delete document.getElementsByClassName;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/nipucuja/1/edit)

That will make the implementation available again via the prototype chain.

#### Old answer

You could try to restore it with this hack:

```
document.getElementsByClassName = document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName
    .bind(document.documentElement);
```

I'm not certain whether it has any downsides, though.

Comment: I guess it depends on how exactly `getElementsByClassName` was overwritten, e.g. if it was overwritten on the prototype, probably neither would help.

Comment: @FelixKling OP mentioned in the comments that this was not the case.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @Pratheep and Jack: apparently this works, but the new (i.e. original) `getElementsByClassName` is not supported by IE8. If it should work in IE8 as well, take a look at my again edited answer.

Comment: Yes, well, jQuery takes care of that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need an implementation of the `getElementsByClassName()`, you may write something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName=function (theclass) {
els=document.getElementsByTagName("*")
temp=[]
for (var k=0; k<els.length; k++) {
if(els[k].className==theclass){
temp.push(els[k])
        }
    }
return temp;    
}
```

And there is a good discussion here that you may refer to: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?256068-Need-object-getElementsByClassName-snippet

Comment: Or just use `return document.querySelectorAll('.' + theclass);` (if IE7 supported is not needed).

Comment: Fails to find elements with more than one attached class.

Comment: I'm using jQuery's class selector which internally uses `getElementsByClassName` so I need to revert that method to its original form.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**, taking Jack's first comment on this answer into account, as well as the edited answer by him:

Deleting `getElementsByClassName` from the prototype chain and thus automatically reverting back to the original function apparently works in itself, but that does leave IE8, which does not support `getElementsByClassName`.

This script comes very close to the original function, takes multiple classes into account, now deals with hyphens correctly, and makes IE8 support it as well:

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(theClass) {
    var elemArray = [];
    var elems = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        var allClasses = elems[i].className;
        var classRegex = new RegExp('^('+theClass+')$|(\\s'+theClass+'\\b)');
        // pattern demo and explanation on http://regex101.com/r/pP8nS2
        if (classRegex.test(allClasses) == true)
            elemArray.push(elems[i]);
    }
    return elemArray;
}
```

Live whole-page demo on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hhswl?editors=100, regex pattern demo and explanation on http://regex101.com/r/pP8nS2.

The only limitation I know is that you cannot use this script in the concatenated form of `document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName(class)`. You should use `document.getElementById(id).querySelectorAll(.class)` for that, which is also supported by IE8 (not 7). Mind the dot.

Comment: The problem with `\b` is that `-` is also considered a non-word.

Comment: That's why jQuery does `(' ' + className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + theClass + ' ')`.

Comment: @Jack: Thanks for the tip! I've been using it quite some time already, to make IE6-8 support `getElementsByClassName()`, but I now see that I've been lucky to have written my class names camelCase. And the `-` is not the only character considered a non-word ~, as I just found out. Characters like ç and é fall under the same category. Edited my answer.